# Nested loop is not returning value in Angular TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a nested loop in a function but it is returning the default value which is false, and not returning the value calculated inside the loop. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

My code is given below. Thank you

```js
     private checkDeliveryNotesQuantity(line: SaleLine): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.posSalesTableFacade.getStoreSaleBlockList$().pipe(
          map((saleBlockList: SaleBlock[]) => {
            saleBlockList.map(saleBlock => {
              saleBlock.saleLineList.map(saleLineList => {
                console.log('saleLineList', saleLineList);
                return (
                  saleLineList.deliveryNotes &&
                  saleLineList.deliveryNotes.findIndex(
                    item => item.articleId === line.code && item.quantity >= line.missingQuantity
                  ) >= 0
                );
              });
            });
            return false;
          })
        );
      }
```

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement in several places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested map lacks return:

```
 private checkDeliveryNotesQuantity(line: SaleLine): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.posSalesTableFacade.getStoreSaleBlockList$().pipe(
          map((saleBlockList: SaleBlock[]) => {
            return saleBlockList.map(saleBlock => {
              return saleBlock.saleLineList.map(saleLineList => {
                console.log('saleLineList', saleLineList);
                return (
                  saleLineList.deliveryNotes &&
                  saleLineList.deliveryNotes.findIndex(
                    item => item.articleId === line.code && item.quantity >= line.missingQuantity
                  ) >= 0
                );
              });
            });
          })
        );
      }
```

Note, that the resulting Observable is going to be of type Array.

In order to fix that you should switch from map to [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
private checkDeliveryNotesQuantity(line: SaleLine): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.posSalesTableFacade.getStoreSaleBlockList$().pipe(
          map((saleBlockList: SaleBlock[]) => {
            return saleBlockList.some(saleBlock => {
              return saleBlock.saleLineList.some(saleLineList => {
                console.log('saleLineList', saleLineList);
                return (
                  saleLineList.deliveryNotes &&
                  saleLineList.deliveryNotes.findIndex(
                    item => item.articleId === line.code && item.quantity >= line.missingQuantity
                  ) >= 0
                );
              });
            });
          })
        );
      }
```

Comment: It is giving an error: 
    TypeError: saleBlockList.some is not a function

      366 |     return this.posSalesTableFacade.getStoreSaleBlockList$().pipe(
      367 |       map((saleBlockList: SaleBlock[]) => {
    > 368 |         return saleBlockList.some(saleBlock => {
          |                              ^
      369 |           return saleBlock.saleLineList.some(saleLineList => {
      370 |             console.log('saleLineList', saleLineList);
      371 |             return (

Comment: This means that getStoreSaleBlockList is not returning an array as the response to pipe(map(...)). You may add a check for this or debug whether the value is of expected type.